# iOS:Add view below navigation bar across viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a project like this:

[image]

But I'm trying to figure out how to add a banner below the navigation bar across the navigation bar in a way where can I hide it if is need it. Any of you knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz use TSMessages.

This library provides an easy to use class to show little notification views on the top of the screen

https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages

Answer (score 2):

In the main view controller implement the protocol `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and in the selector `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` you can manipulate the view controller presented by the navigation controller. e.g:

```
@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}

-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

    UIView *banner = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 10,
                                                              viewController.view.bounds.size.width,30)];
    banner.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [viewController.view addSubview:banner];
}

@end
```

In this example `ViewController` should be the first view controller presented for the `UINavigationController`.

I uploaded an example on [github](https://github.com/FrankFuenmayor/so-ios-simple-banner)

Hope it helps

Comment: Does this implementation can be show in all the viewControllers or just in the main viewController?

Answer (score 0):

for objective-c, use [RMessage](https://github.com/donileo/RMessage)

[image]

for swift, use [SwiftMessages](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages). [Preview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swiftmessages-a-very-flexible-message-bar-for-ios-written-in-swift)